# Maximal Order of Elements in Finite Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite abelian group, then $G$ is isomorphic to a product of cyclic groups.

Suppose $$G \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 .$$
where $ C_2 $ is cyclic of order 2. Then  $\#G=2^3=8$.

**What is the maximal order of an element of $G$?**

If we use additive notation,the generators of $G$ are $(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$, each of which has order $2$.
Thus, it follows that the maximal order of an element of $G$ is 2. (since all other elements have order less that that of the generators).

> Is this argument correct?

If we generalize this: Let $$  G \cong C_{p_1} \times C_{p_2}\times \cdot\cdot\cdot \times C_{p_l} ,$$ where the $p_i$ are primes (not necessarily distinct) dividing the order of $G$. Then $g=(1,1,\cdot \cdot \cdot, 1)$ is a (non-unique) maximal element of $G$ that has order equal to the product of distinct primes dividng  $\#G$.

> How do we know there isn't some other element of higher order? (intuitively, this is kind of obvious, I don't know how to explain it rigorously.)

Comment: For your second example, show that raising/multiplying (multiplicative vs. additive) an arbitrary element to/by the product of the distinct primes will always yield the identity, hence the order of any element divides that number.

Comment: Your argument is incomplete; first, you need to use abelianness; second, your statement is false: it is not true that “all other elements must have order less than that of a generator”. First, it need not be strictly less; and second, it could be more! In $C_{3}\times C_{5}$, the generators $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ have orders $3$ and $5$, respectively, but there are elements of larger order than $3$ and $5$. (Though for an abelian group, no element has order larger than the least common multiple of the orders of the generators in a given generating set; but you need to prove that)

Comment: When you say "I need to use abelianness" that is to show that "for an abelian group, no element has order larger than the least common multiple of the orders of the generators in a given generating set"  right? Or I need it somewhere else in the argument?

Comment: Yes; because that statement is not true for nonabelian groups; for example, the dihedral group of order $2n$ can be generated by two elements of order $2$, but contains elements of order $n$. So the order of an element can be arbitrarily larger than the order of the generators in a nonabelian group.